# Action Script 2 mobile app

Tags: android, flash, actionscript, apk, adobe-air

Чтобы скомпилировать swf, написанный на AS3, в apk, достаточно в Flash Develop создать проект "AIR Mobile AS3 App", и потом с помощью батников создать apk.
Что же можно сделать, если swf написан на AS2?
Спасибо.

Comment: Вкладывать/загружать swf в пробовали? Простым Loader.

Comment: Только что попробовал - не катит...

Comment: Остается декомпилировать и собрать новый.

Comment: То есть переписать на AS3? Охх... это геморой...